# Why iOS Launch Screen then Snapshot then Home Screen?

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

When I kill my iOS app and relaunch it, the quick sequence of screens I see are

1. Launch Screen. The screen defined in `LaunchScreen.storyboard`.
2. Snapshot. The screen image the iPhone created the last time my app was put in the background.
3. Home Screen. The `ViewController` that I set in `AppDelegate`'s `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` method.

From the Apple documentation that I've read, it seemed that during application launch, if a snapshot exists then iOS uses that snapshot *instead of* the launch screen. Why am I seeing both the launch screen *and* the snapshot?

This screen recording shows the issue. The launch screen is red. The home screen is white. The second screen is green. I navigate to the green screen and then put the app in the background to get iOS to take a green screenshot. Then I kill the app. When the app is relaunched, the sequence is launch/red, flash of screenshot/green, home/white. I'm testing on an iPhone 6 with iOS 12.1.1.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqPFq.jpg

From https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623097-ignoresnapshotonnextapplicationl

> As part of the state preservation process, UIKit captures your app’s user interface and stores it in an image file. When your app is relaunched, the system displays this snapshot image in place of your app’s default launch image to preserve the notion that your app was still running.

Comment: Are you using state preservation and calling `ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch()`? If not, what does it have to do with the question? And even if so, if you artificially kill your app there is no state preservation and that method cannot be called.

Comment: I am not calling `ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch()`. I am not using state preservation. It does appear that the app/iOS is doing state preservation as it does create the screenshot.

Comment: Nope, state preservation is something _you_ do or not. The creation of the screenshot has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Does your storyboard have state preservation turned on?

Comment: I'm having the same issues, it's really bugging me for days... In my case, It only happens when multi-window is turned on.

Answer (score 1):

I can't confirm your description. My testing shows that if you kill your app prematurely, then on the next launch the previous backgrounding screen shot is thrown away and the launch screen alone is used.

Here is my test:

- The launch screen is red
- The initial view controller's view is white
- The secondary view controller's view is green

Here is what happens:

1. You will see me launch and then move from the white view to the green view.
2. I then background the app to make sure the snapshot is taken.
3. I then bring the app back to the foreground and then go into the app launcher so you can see the snapshot, which is indeed green.
4. Then I kill the app and relaunch it. I used slow motion in this part of the movie, and you can see clearly that we use the red launch screen and fade to the white of the initial view controller; the green never reappears.

[image]

Perhaps your testing procedure is faulty (test only on a device). Perhaps *you* are launching into the wrong screen and then jumping back to the opening screen (that seems the most likely explanation).

Comment: I recreated your test and still have my same unexpected result. The screenshot/green flashes between launch/white and home/red. Please see the link to the screen recording I added to the original post.

Comment: Cool! Now we need to figure out what the difference is. :)

Comment: This time, I created the app purely with storyboards. Change the color of the launch screen. Wrap the home screen in a navigation controller. Add a button on the home screen to show a second/green screen. That's it. I've done the same with an app that had the `LaunchScreen.storyboard` and all the other views programmatically created and shown. Same results on the iPhone 6.

Comment: Yeah my app is just like yours. — Why do you have a red status bar? What iOS version is this?

Comment: The red status bar is the indication that I'm making a screen recording. I'm using iOS 12.1.1 on iPhone 6. I created the app with Xcode 10.1.

Comment: Me too.  I think you should file a bug report with Apple.

Comment: @TedHenry Its random but i noticed this issue a lot with many apps from i guess `iOS 12` or late `11.xx` on my device  and i think this is from Apple. Some other apps might have the same behavior in your device.